# python opening a file containing integers

Tags: python, python-3.x

New to python, can someone please let me know why is the below code is throwing an error? and suggest me fix

```
def cel_to_fahr(c):
     if c < -273.15:
         return "physical matter can reach only till -273.15"
     else:
         f = c * 9/5 + 32
         return f

temp = open("tempr.txt")
tempr = temp.read()
tempr = tempr.splitlines()

for t in tempr:
    print(cel_to_fahr(t))
```

file content:

```
10
-20
-289
100
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cel_to_fahr.py", line 41, in <module>
    print(cel_to_fahr(t))
  File "cel_to_fahr.py", line 29, in cel_to_fahr
    if c < -273.15:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'
```

Comment: Why are you reading the file all at once and then converting all at once? Just convert the values line by line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite basic python. You could read more about writing and reading files. A common praxis in Python is to use with... open. This will ensure that you close the file after. Consider this example (That works) with with... open. It will also create the file.

```
with open('tempr.txt','w') as f:
    f.write('10\n-20\n-289\n100')

def cel_to_fahr(c):
    if c < -273.15:
        return "physical matter can reach only till -273.15"
    else:
        return c * 9/5 + 32

with open('tempr.txt') as f:
    tempr = [float(i) for i in f.read().split('\n')]

for t in tempr:
    print(cel_to_fahr(t))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, And yes its pretty basic python. As mentioned in the question, I am new to python and as a matter of fact to coding. Again thanks for the answer it worked. I will read more about files.

Comment: @gkiranreddy Don't worry. We are all learning here. I hope you learnt about with open... it is really useful! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Good answers already given, the below will convert to float if accidently a string is used. Also see comments/tips in line:

```
# use type hinting to indicate what type of args should be used
def cel_to_fahr(c: float) -> float:
    # use doc string to describe your function
    """
    usage: a = cel_to_fahr(x)
    x = degrees celcius (pos/neg) as float
    a = return degrees fahrenheit (pos/neg) as float

    Will raise ValueError when x < -273.15
    """
    # you can change to float if it is not float or int to begin with
    c = c if isinstance(c, (float, int)) else float(c)
    # check if c is indeed 0 K (-273.15 C) or up
    if c >= -273.15:
        return c * 9/5 + 32
    # Errors should never pass silently.
    # Unless explicitly silenced.
    raise ValueError('Physical matter can reach only till -273.15')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a string with a float, try this instead:

```
def cel_to_fahr(c):
     if c < -273.15:
         return "physical matter can reach only till -273.15"
     else:
         f = c * 9/5 + 32
         return f

temp = open("tempr.txt")
tempr = temp.read()
tempr = tempr.splitlines()

for t in tempr:
    print(cel_to_fahr(float(t)))
```

Assuming there that you have only float in your file.

The data read from a file, are read as a string until you cast them.

If you are unsure about the format of data, you can use a try/catch logic. But for your simple question where all the data are know in your file, this would be overkill.

Comment: @gkiranreddy based on the error message, it looks like you only applied the first float conversion, not the second.

Comment: I would actually suggest doing something like `cel_to_fahr(float(t))` when you originally call the function

Comment: I tried your suggestions and got the below error:

  File "cel_to_fahr.py", line 33
    return f   
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: @Luc I just read last line of your comment "Assuming there that you have only float in your file" - I am just passing integers positive and negative values

Comment: indentation error means that you missed a space when you copied/pasted. Integer are included in float, so it should be good :)